# Map NativeQuery to POJO

Tags: java, jpa, nativequery

I have a NativeQuery which I want to map to a POJO.

I tried the following but it ends in an infinite loop.

```
public synchronized List<FreeIP> getFirstFreeHost() {
    String q = "SELECT i.subnet, h.ip_host FROM ip_addresses i join hosts h on i.id = h.ip_addresses_id ORDER BY i.subnet, h.ip_host";
    this.entityManager = this.entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    Query query = this.entityManager.createNativeQuery(q);
    List<Object[]> rows = query.getResultList();
    List<FreeIP> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Object[] row : rows) {
        result.add(new FreeIP((String) row[0], (String) row[1]));
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at QLRM: https://github.com/simasch/qlrm

Then you can do:

```
JpaResultMapper jpaResultMapper = new JpaResultMapper();

Query q = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT i.subnet, h.ip_host FROM ip_addresses i join hosts h on i.id = h.ip_addresses_id ORDER BY i.subnet, h.ip_host");

List<EmployeeTO> list = jpaResultMapper.list(q, FreeIP.class);
```

Make sure that FreeIP has a constructor that takes all arguments of your query.